# The domain in which $\operatorname{Ln}(\frac{i-z}{i+z})$ can be evaluated.

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

In which domain can we evaluate$$\operatorname{Ln} \left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)$$

I am told that it can be evaluated when $z\neq \pm ia,a\geq 1$

I do not see how to figure out. I am trying to do it by setting $$\arg\left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)\in[0,\pm\pi[$$ but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: $z=\pm i$ are branch points.  A single-valued branch can be defined by making a branch cut joining those 2 points.  The branch cut you suggest ($z\neq \pm ia,a\geq 1$) joins the points "through infinity."

Comment: what are branch points? Could you add some more detail?

Comment: Branch points are a type of non-isolated singularity.  For example $z=0$ is a branch point of the logarithm or the square root function.  A "multi-valued" complex function is discontinuous in a circuit around a branch point.  Typically the argument doesn't return to its starting value.

Comment: OK. But i don't really understand the details of how to figure out these so called branch cuts

Comment: You want to prevent your function from being able to wrap completely around a branch point which requires a series of one or more branch cuts (depending on the number of branch points).  The logarithm has branch points at 0 and inifinity, so the usual solution is to make a branch cut between 0 and infinity along the negative real axis.  In your case the argument of log is $(i-z)/(i+z)$, so you need to look at the pre-images of 0 and infinity.  Those will be the branch points.  Make a convenient branch cut, and you should get a single-valued branch.